# How to fix RAW drives?

Tags: windows-7, usb

I have a 2 GB kingston USB stick , the file system became RAW. How can I reformat it to use it again.I have tried many utilities but nothing worked, I'm using windows7.

Comment: What utilities have you tired, and what errors have you gotten

Comment: I used Active@ killdisk, and I get "unwritable sector" error

Comment: and cmd lines, but didn't work

Comment: Maybe consider [edit]ing your question and adding every detail (rather than posting it as comments). Especially, which command lines.

Comment: You should try using the Disk Management tool under Computer Management (right-click on Computer and choose Manage) but it is likely that the stick is faulty and will need to be thrown away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before throwing away your flash drive, please try using an Ubuntu Live CD to delete any partition that may be present and then format it using even disk manager or terminal